# Reparar bucle while infinito

Tags: python, python-2.7, while, bucles

Tengo este programa para resolver dentro de la resolución tengo un bucle `while` infinito y no se como ponerlo, ya que si uso un `break` salgo de la `funcion` y no puedo seguir introduciendo datos a mi programa.

Tiene que verificarse con el siguiente ejemplo:

- Input |  Result
- 6     |  Valor 1 = 6; múltiplo de 3
- 10    |  Valor 2 = 10;
- 6    |  Valor 3 = -6; múltiplo de 3
- 10   |  Valor 4 = -10;
- 0 |  FIN: 2 múltiplos de 3

```html
m=int(raw_input(""))
t=0
pares=0
while m>=0:
  t=t+1
  if m%2==0:
    pares=pares+1
    l="par"
  else:
    l="impar"
print "Valor",t,"=",m,";",l
```

Comment: El while tiene una condición, mientras m>=0 pero en ningún momento lo modificas y por eso es un bucle, podrías intentar restarle por cada operación 1, es decir m-=1 o cambiar la condición, ejemplo while t<m.

Comment: este es el Ejercicio: Realice un programa en Python con las siguientes caracteristicas: Pedir al usuario valores enteros positivos hasta que ingrese un valor negativo. Ir mostrando por pantalla numero de orden, valor ingresado y si es par o impar. (ver formato en el ejemplo) Al finalizar la carga, mostrar la cantidad de pares ingresados. por lo que yo entiendo lo que determina si pido un valor mas o no es depende lo que ingrese el usuario, como podria hacer ese while entonces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para poder ingresar varios números necesitas un while que te pida numeros hasta que alguno sea negativo, en este caso la variable seria la entrada.

```
def main():
    t=0
    pares=0
    m=int(input(""))
    if m>=0:
        if m%2==0:
            print('par')
        else:
            print('impar') 
        while m>=0:
          m=int(input(""))
          t=t+1
          if m%2==0:
            pares=pares+1
            l="par"
          else:
            l="impar"
          print(l)

main()
```

con esto te garantizas de que los números que ingreses y almacenes sean mayores a 0, ten presente que cuando se trata de ciclos y entradas, debes tener cuidado si va adentro o si va afuera, aquí debe estar adentro porque es la que va variar y la condición es mientras la entrada sea mayor o igual a cero.

Answer (score 1):

El bucle es infinito debido a que la condición de salida la marca la variable `m`, que en ningún momento es modificada dentro del bucle.

Por otra parte, si necesitas seguir introduciendo valores, necesitas colocar la entrada de texto dentro del bucle y para la salida utilizar, por ejemplo un caracter concreto (como 0 por ejemplo), pero, con el ejemplo que das, nunca deberías comprobar `m` como condición de salida.

Comment: este es el Ejercicio:  Realice un programa en Python con las siguientes caracteristicas:

Pedir al usuario valores enteros positivos hasta que ingrese un valor negativo.
Ir mostrando por pantalla numero de orden, valor ingresado y si es par o impar. (ver formato en el ejemplo)
Al finalizar la carga, mostrar la cantidad de pares ingresados.                     por lo que yo entiendo lo que determina si pido un valor mas o no es depende lo que ingrese el usuario, como podria hacer ese while entonces?